# SpaceX CRS-11 landing pad debris identification

Tags: spacex, falcon-9, landing

After sending [CRS-11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SpaceX_CRS-11) into orbit to rendezvous with the space station, the first stage of the SpaceX rocket Dragon landed on Landing Zone one.

In [the video released subsequently](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GrP3jHuLQ9o) you can see two pieces of debris kicked up by the landing blast to the right of the landing spacecraft:

[image]
[image]

What are these, and is this an accident or intentional?

Comment: General consensus in the forata seems to be a piece of FOD left behind.  But no clear evidence either way that i have seen yet.